# Derivative of a tricky piecewise function at a jump

Tags: calculus, derivatives

to be up front this is a homework problem,
this is a graph of f(x) and i am intrested in calculating the value f'(0)

[image]

My thought is that it would be -1 because the left and right limits would agree that the slope is the same on either side, but it might also be undefined because of the jump?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to explain why you think the jump may mean that the derivative is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that "the left and right limits would agree that the slope is the same on either side." Recall that the derivative of $f$ exists at $a$ if the limit $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$$ exists. Taking $a=0,$ the limit from the left hand side gives us $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{-h - 0}{h} = -1 \; $$ as you suggest. From the right hand side however we have $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1-h - 0}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1-h}{h} $$ which obviously doesn't work out.

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the theorem :

> If $f(x)$ is not continuos at $x=a$, then $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=a$